# Apps from Google Play without logging into to Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google

I want to get apps from Google Play without logging in to Google Play or using a google account.  I just dont want google to have this information.

Is it possible ?

Comment: [Aurora Store](https://gitlab.com/AuroraOSS/AuroraStore) offers an anonymous login option.

Comment: I have read about cleanapk.org which aims to provide important apps from Google Play for non-Google devices and CustomROM such as `/e/`. But I have not found out how to use cleanapk.org.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to access google play without an account but many of the apts on the play store can be downloaded from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/).

Comment: I wouldn't say *many*. :)

Comment: In fact very few.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are some alternatives to the GooglePlay Store out there - all with different approaches. F-Droid's goal is to provide only FOSS (free open source sofware) Apps.
Others would be for example https://apkpure.com/

Back to you main question: YES you can access the Google Play Store and load Apps directly from there without an Google Account. As mentioned in the commends one popular solution is the Aurora Store (also available on F-Droid). What it does is, it takes your request and sends it with an faked Account to the Google Play API to get the Apps. So Google will log that an App was downloaded, maybe some more information like Country (not sure what is required by the API) BUT without your real identity.